# codeigniter form submit with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have search for a day for find a better tutorial for codeigniter form submit in ajax, unfortunately I couldn't find a better one or clear one. In stack overflow also there is no directbetter solution for it. there mention only about ajax part. there is no mentioned way for how to access from controller and how to submit and display response in view. I think it's better if any one can provide a better guidance for this.thank you!

this is what I have tried...

**view**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" name="myForm1" id="myForm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    Question: <input type="text" name="qText" id="qText">
    <input id="submitbutton" type="submit">
    </form>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>   //no need to specify the language
       $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#myForm1').submit(function(e) {

            var form = $(this);
            var dataString = $("#myForm1").serialize();
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('form_controller/insert_into_db'); ?>",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data){
                    alert("success");

                },
                error: function() { alert("Error posting feed."); }
           });

        });
        });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

**controller**

```
<?php
class Form_controller extends CI_controller{

function index(){
    $this->load->view('submit_form');
}
public function insert_into_db(){
return true;
}

}
```

**model**

```
 <?php

 class Form_model extends CI_Model{

function insertQ(){
    echo $email = $this->input->post('email');
    echo $text = $this->input->post('qText')
    $this->db->query("insert into form (email,text) values('$email','$text')");

}
```

Comment: I have tried for a day, may I send you my code,I thought if I show my code,it'll be complicated for new one those who try to find answer for this question...

Comment: @ Manwal Error posting feed.

Comment: I can't understand post your error log.

Comment: @ Manwal see ajax function in my view, in success alert

Comment: Is success not alerting???

Comment: @ Manwal yes only alert error msg

Comment: don't use `return true;` in controller function use `echo true;`. And check network tab in browser developer tool to check ajax activity.

Comment: @ Manwal its  not working

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:
1. call  insertQ() from controller function insert_into_db(). No need of return true.
2. create new view file and load in controller function insert_into_db().
3. in ajax success function load response in any div.

ex:

```
public function insert_into_db(){
   $this->Form_model->insertQ();
   $this->load->view('success_view');
}
```

javascript ajax function :

```
success: function(data){
    $('abc').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The  Most Simple Method as follows

View

```
     <form method="post" name="myForm1" id="myForm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
     Question: <input type="text" name="qText" id="qText">
     <input id="submitbutton" onclick="sub();" type="submit">
     </form>

      <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {

       function sub()
       {
              var dataString = $("#myForm1").serialize();
          $.post("<?php echo site_url('form_controller/insert_into_db');?>",
          {
            vals: dataString,
          },
         function(response)
         { 

          });
        }
       });
     </script>
```

Controller

```
function insert_into_db()
  {

    $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
    $data['qtext'] = $this->input->post('qtext');
    $this->modelname->insertQ($data)
  }
```

Model

```
public function insertQ($dat)
   {
    if($this->db->insert('table_name',$dat))
    {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we call a function using ajax, that function should echo or print something.. Anything printed or echoed by a PHP script, ie any output, that has been requested by an ajax call, will be returned to the client as a response.

In controller

```
<?php
class Form_controller extends CI_controller{

function index(){
    $this->load->view('submit_form');
}
public function insert_into_db(){
   $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
    $data['qtext'] = $this->input->post('qtext');
    $response = $this->modelname->insertQ($data)
    echo $reponse;

}

}
```

For detailed information regarding ajax ,please refer the following link..  It may help you

http://webdevelopingcat.com/jquery-php-beginner-tutorial-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Form_controller extends CI_controller{
function index(){
    $this->load->view('submit_form');
}
public function insert_into_db(){
$this->load->model('Form_model');  
$response = $this->Form_model->insertQ();
echo $response;
}
}
```

You did not echo anything in the controller and also you have not instantiated your model. change your controller to this and try again.